# Running multiple apps on multiple ports through rack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra, rack, thin

I am trying to run two apps on 2 instances of thin on different ports
something like

> in config.ru

`run App1, port: 3000
 run App2, port: 4567`

how can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Since it's two apps, you can't start them simultaneously in one config.ru.

If they're separated to two apps, start them like

```
# for App1
thin -R config.ru -a 127.0.0.1 -p 3000 start
# for App2
thin -R config.ru -a 127.0.0.1 -p 4567 start
```

or specify the port in `config.ru` first line directly, take App1 for example

```
#\ -p 3000
...
...

run App1
```

Comment: I want a single command "rackup config.ru" to run both apps on different ports and so i am looking for the code needed to be placed in the config.ru to achieve this behavior if possible